# I don't see the result of running custom code

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I use wordpress, elementor and plugin to run custom php code: PHP Code Snippets.

I want to create a custom user logout page. The problem is that when I add the code to the plugin, put the appropriate shortcode on the page, after opening it in the browser I do not see the effects of the code - the user is not logged out. I open page and nothing happen.

I added logs and I can see that all functions are performed or at least do not throw errors, but the user remains logged in and is not redirected to the home page.

Interestingly, when I try to edit a page in elementor and open it in the elementor editor, the php code associated with the shortcode immediately executes perfectly and is logged out and moved to the main page.

Here's the code I'm having trouble with.

```
<?php

wp_destroy_current_session();

wp_clear_auth_cookie();

do_action( 'wp_logout' );

wp_redirect(  'https://myPage.com' );


?>
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you enabled WP debug mode, and checked if that raises any errors? Redirecting will not be possible any more, once output has already been sent to the client - and with a shortcode, that gets executed somewhere in your page's actual _content_, that is probably not the case any more.